# How to clear out the contents of a map when clear() method call throws UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: java, exception, collections

How can I empty a map contents if  I  keep getting an  `UnsupportedOperationException` when I call `clear()` method on the map instance  ?

Comment: Apparently, this map doesn't support this operation. Create a new one.

Comment: Maybe an unmodifiable map, and they want to indicate you need different logic, using your own map filling it with that map.

Comment: check code of .clear() of your Map implementation. Post it if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't. There is something wrong in the contracts of the collaborating objects and their methods. You expect a modifiable map, but get an unmodifiable view. You should redefine the contracts and/or adopt any of the implementations accordingly. If you are not in control of the one, who is passing you that map, then there is probably a reason for it passing you an unmodifiable view.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Map` is an `UnmodifiableMap` (for instance, gotten from [`Collections.unmodifiableMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29)), there's little you can (*and should*) do to modify it, except creating a new reference and clearing it.

```
Map unmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
Map newMap = new HashMap(unmodifiable);
newMap.clear();
unmodifiable = newMap;
```

That said, it is actually possible to modify an `UnmodifiableMap`. It turns out that [`Collections.UnmodifiableMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.UnmodifiableMap) is nothing more than a class implementing the `Map` interface, and wrapping the actual `Map`. It delegates on the wrapped `Map` for its read-only methods, and throws `UnsupportedOperationException`s in its implementations of methods that alter the map. It is possible to get the wrapped `Map` by reflection, and therefore modify it.

**DISCLAIMER**: Take into account that this must be used with extreme caution. If the unmodifiable map is provided by a a library or similar, it might be making assumptions about its nature, and violateing its contract can lead to unexpected/undesirable results. Also, this might be relying on internals that might be changed without notice or differ between versions.

```
// Creates a standard map
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
myMap.put("1", "a");
myMap.put("2", "b");
// Creates an unmodifiableMap. Actually a wrapper for myMap.
Map unmodifiableMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(myMap);
System.out.println("Size of unmodifiable map is: " + unmodifiableMap.size());
try{
    // Get classes declared in java.util.Collections
    Class[] classes = Collections.class.getDeclaredClasses();
    for(Class cl : classes) {
        // Look for the UnmodifiableMap class
        if("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap".equals(cl.getName())) {
            // The wrapped Map is in an attribute called "m"
            Field field = cl.getDeclaredField("m");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            // Get the wrapped map
            Object obj = field.get(unmodifiableMap);
            Map map = (Map) obj;
            // modify it
            map.clear();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e){ System.out.println(); }
System.out.println("Size of unmodifiable map is: " + unmodifiableMap.size());
```

(credit to [this blog post](http://delta-codes.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/modifying-unmodifiable-map.html))