# Why UIComponentBase class doesn't expose a setAttribute() method?

Tags: java, jsf

[UIComponentBase](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html) does have a  `public abstract Map<String, Object> getAttributes()` method but doesn't have a setAttributes()  method .Why is this  designed like this ? I am assuming that the designers wanted to make his map unmodifiable but why so ?

My requirement is to clean up all the attributes of a component . How would I do so instead of calling each of the setters ? I can not call clear() on the attributes map because [it throws a UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14772132/1527084)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's not "just" a `HashMap` or so. It's a customized map with the following specific features as mentioned in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29):

> The returned implementation must support all of the standard and optional Map methods, plus support the following additional requirements:
>
> - The `Map` implementation must implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.
> - Any attempt to add a `null` key or value must throw a `NullPointerException`.
> - Any attempt to add a key that is not a `String` must throw a `ClassCastException`.
> - If the attribute name specified as a key matches a property of this `UIComponent`'s implementation class, the following methods will have special behavior:
>
>   - `containsKey` - Return `false`.
>   - `get()` - If the property is readable, call the getter method and return the returned value (wrapping primitive values in their corresponding wrapper classes); otherwise throw `IllegalArgumentException`.
>   - `put()` - If the property is writeable, call the setter method to set the corresponding value (unwrapping primitive values in their corresponding wrapper classes). If the property is not writeable, or an attempt is made to set a property of primitive type to `null`, throw `IllegalArgumentException`.
>   - `remove` - Throw `IllegalArgumentException`.

Particularly the `get()` is special. It doesn't "just" return the value associated with the map key, but it actually invokes a getter method on the current component, e.g. `component.getFoo()` when `component.getAttributes().get("foo")` is requested. Those getter methods in turn usually delegate to the `StateHelper`.

The `setAttributes()` would allow overriding and thus breaking this contract and possibly cause the whole JSF component tree working to fail.

Comment: At least not via `getAttributes()`. Invoke the setters individually or, depending on the moment, recreate the component. This is by the way a crazy functional requirement. Are you sure that you're looking for the solution in the right direction?

Comment: I have the option of calling individual setters but I wanted a more elegant way.